# Unity stretch scrollview bottom to the bottom of the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to stretch the scrollview's bottom to the bottom of the Screen.
I tried with

```
scrollViewItemRt = (RectTransform)scrollViewItem.transform;
scrollViewItemRt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, -Screen.height);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the settings on the scroll view? If I recall correctly, if you've set it to flex then it shrinks to your content if there is less content than your dimensions.

Comment: I have a button under the scroll view, and if that button is not visible I want to stretch the whole scroll view to the botton of the screen

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about your scroll view settings, though. If you can disable flex and the sizing works as intended then you should toggle flex with the show/hide on the button. I don't have a project with UI stuff right now and I'm too lazy to make a shell project just to answer this question; it'd be a lot easier if you could please share your settings and/or give this a try.

Comment: I don't really understand what flex is.:) Which settings do you need? The scroll view works correct. I only would like to increase its height programatically if below there is nothing on the screen. The main problem is, how to determine the gap's height to the bottom of the screen and how to stretch down the scroll view

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm thinking of the UI Toolkit, which uses uxml, uss, etc. to make a CSS-style UI. There's a [description here on the differences](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UI-system-compare.html). UI Toolkit has a [flex option, `flexGrow`, `flexDirection`, etc.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-LayoutEngine.html), but I think your scrollview is using a [Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html). For the content fitter the setting I think you're looking for is vertical fit: Min Size or Preferred Size.

Comment: That said, if you could explain more what exactly you mean when you say, "it doesn't work," then maybe there's some other details that could explain what's happening. I thought you had a setting set that kept your UI element to a minimal value (Min Size, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your ScrollView is a child of a `Canvas` which covers the screen, and not a child of any sub-object that only covers part of the screen.

In the ScrollView's RectTransform, pick one of the options that makes it stretch vertically:

[image: RectTrasform aligned left, stretch vertically]

such as the one highlighted. The ones in the bottom row here, with the blue ↕ character, will all work.

Then, the `PosY` and `Height` options will change to `Top` and `Bottom`. Make sure they are both 0, or small numbers if you want a little padding.